# how to make the items of listView Continuous changing dynamicly in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, listview

there. I'm starting to learn animation in Flutter and I don't know how to make the listview of item appear automatically  like this video: [see this video](https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/stateguide-7163e.appspot.com/o/demo.mp4?alt=media&token=51217f36-6aea-4e14-94a6-644e70f22315)

Comment: I used this  package it's useful flutter_banner_swiper: ^0.1.4

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the [PageView](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/PageView-class.html) class.

For Autoscrolling you can checkout **Timer and PageController**

This is sample way of how you can achieve that:

Declare the Controller and Page Number

```
int _currentPage = 0;
PageController _pageController = PageController(
  initialPage: 0,
);
```

Initiating the Timer and then navigating to the next item using PageController

```
@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 5), (Timer timer) {
    if (_currentPage < 2) {
      _currentPage++;
    } else {
      _currentPage = 0;
    }

    _pageController.animateToPage(
      _currentPage,
      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 350),
      curve: Curves.easeIn,
    );
  });
}
```

Finally calling the build method with the view

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return PageView(
      controller: _pageController,
      children: [
        Container(
          child: Text("1"),
        ),
        Container(
          child: Text("2"),
        ),
        Container(
          child: Text("3"),
        ),
      ],
    );
}
```

Comment: thanks @soumik-bhattacharjee, do you any plugin or widget that already exist that provide this animation, or can you explain to me how to implement this timer in a listView builder widget.

Comment: Ok added a sample code of how you can achieve this feat. Not tested as I am not on my IDE right now, But the process should be this

Comment: Thanks bro but I don't want the current page because I have other widgets

Answer (score 1):

You can use this package(https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_banner_swiper). Or take a look at this repository and make ur custom with help of it.

There's also another package with null-safety(https://pub.dev/packages/banner_carousel)

Comment: @kopoyo if it helps, mark it as correct answer. It would be helpful for others.

Comment: Unfortunately this package doesn't support null safety.

Comment: @kopoyo check above package

Comment: I find this package it's work : flutter_banner_swiper: ^0.1.4